# Windows 7 How to write to "Programs Folder\app directory" using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, security, windows-7

I have developed software and am trying to protect it from being copied from one machine to another by writing all of the machine MAC addresses to a text file in the root apps folder for the program on the first run of the app.  Everytime the app is run thereafter it checks to see if the text file is there and compares data in the text file to the mac addresses on the computer it is being run on.   If they are differant the program fails  to run.

If someone tried to just copy the directory they would also copy the text file and when they tried to run the app on another computer it would fail.

It is not a problem to write something to the virtual store but the program can then be copied and run on a unauthorized machine.

I need to write one text file one time.

Thanks, Myles

Comment: This is a bad idea. Not only is it a pretty ineffective copy protection system, it doesn't work on systems with UAC enabled since apps can't write to the Program Files directory.

I'd try to figure something else out instead.

Comment: And if someone copies everything but the textfile... What then?

Comment: So if my network card breaks your app would then no longer work for me? Or if I unplug my USB wireless adapter? I'm sorry, but that's a terrible way to check for copying of software. If you used the serial number of the Windows installation or something it might be reasonable, but to use information from a piece of hardware that can be changed that easily is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

With UAC enabled you can't do that without the user's permission. Write data files to the user's app data folder instead...

Comment: What I have found is; Most eveyone, not all, will copy the entire app directory since they do not know if they need the txt file or not. I would be fairly tough to figure out what was causing the app not to run. The txt file is currently written to the virtual store user app data wher UAC are inforced. I do not want to disable UAC. I need a one time write for the Vista/W7 systems.

Comment: It does not write MAC for plug and play:
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Public Class mac_address_getter
    Private netcardname, mac_id As String
    Private networkcard() As NetworkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    Private Iobj As NetworkInterface
    Public Function MAC_getter() As String
        For Each Iobj In networkcard
            netcardname = Iobj.Description
            mac_id = mac_id & netcardname & "  " & Iobj.Id.ToString & vbNewLine
        Next
        Return mac_id
    End Function

End Class

Answer (score 1):

You got only one shot at this, which is all you need.  The setup.exe program for your app will run with admin privileges.  Write a custom action to get that file created.

I'll avoid talking about the merits of security through obscurity.  Or the enormous trouble you'll get into when an important client suddenly can't use mission critical software anymore because of a hardware upgrade.

Comment: In general when you live in a UAC world take all the things you used to do "on first run" and do them on install. The install is elevated, the first run isn't. Like Hans I will withhold comment on the merits of your overall plan.